# Custom Entity Framework configuration file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration

I am using Entity Framework. The connection string is currently saved in the `app.config` file, which by default creates a new file called `APPLICATION_NAME.exe.config` and copies it to the output folder when building.

Now I don't want my connection string to be visible to the world when I am creating applications, so one way is to create another config file as a resource and reference it in the application.

**EDIT**:

I am developing using WPF, now is there any special configuration for it doing the below:

1. How to register an embedded config file in the application ?
2. Normally when you create your own `DbContext`, you pass the connection string like this

   ```
   public MyDBContext() : base("name=Connection_String_Name_In_AppConfig")
   ```

   so how to tell the `DbContext` classes to take the connection string from the newly created config file?

Comment: Is there a problem if you just read connection string from some mysterious place and pass it directly to the DBContext?

Comment: Can this mysterious place be a config file :)

Comment: Sure. Your question is now "How to read from an embedded config file" and there are plenty of samples out there. You just need to read the config manually with code, not automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. How to register an embedded config file in the Application

You do not. But nothing stops you do "program" code that takes your own configuration information from wherever you want and uses that.

> Q2. How to tell DBContext classes to take the DB connection from the newly created config 
>   file ?

You do not. But you can actually pass in an code created connection toe a DbCOntext, in case you did not see that in the documentation.

And seriously, NOTHING in here has ANY relationship to WPF, so that tag you added is just not a good smart move.

Answer (score 0):

1. To embed a file into the assembly, select the file in the solution explorer and go to Property window then select Build Action as 'Embedded Resource' and Copy to Output Directory as 'Do not copy'. This way the XML config file will get embedded in the assembly.
2. Now in your Host application(here WPF), you can read the resource file content and then pass the connection string data to your DBContext.

**Example to read embedded file from the assembly:**

```
private const string strFileName = “XMLFile.config”;
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStreamthis.GetType(), strFileName);
var doc = new XmlDocument();

try
{
   if (stream == null)
   {
      throw new FileNotFoundException(“Couldnot find embedded mappings resource file.”,        strFileName);
   }
   doc.Load(stream);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Hope this will help you

I have a sample application hosted on [Github](https://github.com/pradudev/EmbeddedResourceEFConsoleDemo) that exactly does what you want.

Comment: This will find the file in any place in the solution even if the file is under a subfolder ?

Comment: Nope. This will only find the files that are embedded to the current assembly